# Strategy for versioning dependencies between spring-ws-core and spring-* dependencies

Tags: java, spring, spring-ws

The current latest build (2.4.0.RELEASE) depends on spring-* 4.2.7.RELEASE versions. In branch master, spring-ws depends on 4.2.8.SNAPSHOT (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ws/blob/master/build.gradle).

This gives all sorts of NoSuchMethodError and NoClassDefFoundErrors withour explicit excludes on these transitive dependencies.

What is the current strategy for dependencies between Spring Web Services (i.e. spring-ws-core) and other Spring artifacts? It would be quite useful if these releases were alligned with each other. Specifically since spring-ws 2.4.0.RELEASE is from October '16 and spring-* 4.2.8 is from July '16, whereas spring-* 4.3.3.RELEASE is from September 16.

EDIT: Although there is no response here, there are gradle profiles in the master branch so it is at least possible to checkout from source and publish these artifacts on your own, i.e. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ws/blob/master/spring4-next-profile.gradle and https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ws/blob/master/spring5-profile.gradle. The former was touched some months ago and the latter a couple of weeks ago.